# javascript, how to check if a char is any of the following?

Tags: javascript

for example
`var currentWord = "hello.";`

how can I check if the currentWord ends in a `"." "," "!" "?" ";" ":"` ?

Do I have to have a bunch of if else statements?
This is the code I have right now, that works, but is really redundant

```
if (
  currentWord.slice(-1) == "." || 
  currentWord.slice(-1) == "," || 
  currentWord.slice(-1) == "!" || 
  currentWord.slice(-1) == "?" || 
  currentWord.slice(-1) == "?" || 
  currentWord.slice(-1) == ";" || 
  currentWord.slice(-1) == ":"
) {
```

Comment: regular expressions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FRegular_Expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expression like this. This wouldn't require using slice if you didn't want to use it.

```
if (currentWord.match(/[\.,!?;:]$/)) {
alert("matched");
}
```

This would still work though ...

```
if (currentWord.slice(-1).match(/[\.,!?;"]/)) {
alert("matched");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried using the top statement you had and it worked perfectly! Thanks for the help

Comment: The `.` character doesn't need to be escaped inside of a character set. See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array of the characters and then use the [`.indexOf()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf). In this case you could simply use `chars.indexOf(currentWord.slice(-1)) > -1` where `chars` is an array composed of the characters.

```js
var currentWord = "hello.",
    chars = [".", ",", "!", "?", ";", ":"],
    endsInChar = chars.indexOf(currentWord.slice(-1)) > -1;

console.log(endsInChar); // true
```

Alternatively, you could use a basic regular expression along with the [`.test()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

In this case, you could use `/[.,!?;:]$/.test(currentWord)` where `[.,!?;:]` is a character set of the characters and `$` is an anchor asserting the end of the string.

```js
var currentWord = "hello.",
    endsInChar = /[.,!?;:]$/.test(currentWord);

console.log(endsInChar); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

While it can be done with regular expressions, I prefer arrays

```
// warning, typed on the fly, untested
var punc = ['.', '?'];
var lastChar = currentWord.slice(-1);
if (punc.indexOf(lastChar) >= 0) {
   // Ended with a punctuation symbol
} else {
   // Otherwise
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many people prefer the array option, however, regular expressions are a very useful tool and you might as well use them.

For example:

```
var word = prompt("Word?")

alert(/[\.,!\?;:]$/.test(word))
```

The reason for the backslashes is that:

- `.` in regexes means any character, we want a literal `.`.
- `?` in regexes makes the preceding token optional, God knows what that does in `[]`.

So, therefore, I escaped those characters.